# Create a class with dynamic property names in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to have a class in powershell where I can create the names of the properties of that class dynamically. For example,

```
$binFiles = Get-ChildItem $files -Include *.BIN -recurse
$binFiles.Name
```

This would print something like:

File1.BIN

ThisFile.BIN

...

FileOther.BIN

I want these file names to be the names of the properties in my class that I will create multiple times.  Is this even possible?

```
Class myItem {
    [String]$"File1.BIN"
    [String]$"ThisFile.BIN"
    ....
    [String]$"FileOther.BIN"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Invoke-Expression` (the solution is PSv5+, due to using custom PS classes):

```
Invoke-Expression @"
Class myItem {
  $((Get-ChildItem $files -Include *.BIN -recurse).ForEach({"[string] `${$($_.Name)}`n "}))
}
"@
```

<sup>**Note**: While this particular use of `Invoke-Expression` is safe, because you fully control the string being evaluated, [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).</sup>

The here-string produces the class definition as a *string*, which `Invoke-Expression` then evaluates, which defines class `[myItem]` for later use (e.g., `$instance = [myItem]::new()`).

Note:

- The class definition statically creates properties based on the files present *at the time you call `Invoke-Expression`*.
- Extending a class *dynamically* isn't directly supported<sup>[1]</sup>, but you can *recreate* the class later based on the then-current set of files, simply by repeating the `Invoke-Expression` call.<sup>[2]</sup>

The here-string produced above looks something like this - note the need to enclose the property names in `{...}`, because they contain `.`:

```
Class myItem {
  
  [string] ${File1.Bin}
  [string] ${File2.Bin}
  # ...
 
}
```

---

<sup>[1] A class is *immutable* once defined, although you could add properties dynamically to its *instances* using PowerShell's ETS (extended type system), typically via the `Add-Member` cmdlet.

Adding *instance* properties on demand would enable [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician)'s suggestion of alternatively defining the class without properties and only an (instance) method that populates / updates a given instance's properties on demand.</sup>

<sup>[2] Technically, the recreated class is a *distinct .NET type*, though that typically won't matter, given that referring to it via a type literal - `[myItem]` in this case - works the same.</sup>

Comment: Good point, @Blaisem: it will; please see my update.