# In what scenario was Invoke-Expression designed to be used?

Tags: powershell

9/10 times if you are trying to use the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet, there is a better way. Building the arguments to a command dynamically? Use an array of arguments. Building the arguments to a cmdlet? Use splatting with an array or hashtable. Your command has a space in the path to it? Use the call operator (`&`).

This might seem open ended, but `Invoke-Expression` is an easily accessible cmdlet where the answer is almost always to never use it. But the cmdlet exists for a reason, is not deprecated, and most criticisms of its use state something similar to, "it's almost never the right answer", but never states when it is acceptable to use it. In what case is it acceptable to use `Invoke-Expression`? Or to word it a bit less openly, how was `Invoke-Expression` designed to be used?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Update*: An official deep-dive topic is now available: [Avoid using Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression)

---

To quote from a **PowerShell team blog post** titled **[*Invoke-Expression considered harmful*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)** (emphasis added):

> The bottom line: Invoke-Expression is a powerful and *useful command for some scenarios such as creating new scripts at runtime*, but in general, **if you find yourself using `Invoke-Expression`, you should ask yourself, or maybe a respected colleague if there is a better way**.

[EBGreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1358/ebgreen) notes:

> Or to phrase it another way, It [Invoke-Expression] is ok to use as long as a user is never involved in any part of generating the string that will be invoked. But even then, not using it will enforce better habits than using it would.

In short:

- **As a matter of habit, always consider a different (usually more robust and secure) solution first**.
- **If you do find that `Invoke-Expression` is your only choice, carefully consider the security implications**: if a string from an (untrusted) outside source (e.g., user input) is passed directly to `Invoke-Expression`, arbitrary commands may be executed.

  - Therefore: **Only use `Invoke-Expression` if you fully control or implicitly trust the input.**

---

***Rare* examples of justified (safe) use of `Invoke-Expression`**:

- Effectively dot-sourcing PowerShell initialization code,

  - if [provided via the output from a trusted executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76594331/45375).
- Creating PSv5+ custom classes *dynamically*:

  - [so that the class can be used in a remote session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59923349/45375).
  - [so that the set of properties can be created based on conditions at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49117370/45375).
- Using `Invoke-Expression` in combination with `Write-Output`:

  - to [parse a string with embedded quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51229037/45375), *with extra precautions*.
  - to [parse command lines stored in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60328737/45375), *if trusted*.
- Using `Invoke-Expression` for *nested property access*:

  - via [a property path stored in a *string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68463377/45375).

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question, and I can still think of other techniques other than using `Invoke-Expression` for running scripts entirely constructed within Powershell for most circumstances. So my takeaway is that there is ***always*** a better solution than `Invoke-Expression`.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest: Glad to hear it. I wouldn't say always, but in most cases; please see my update.

Comment: Both cases I did not take into consideration, though I can't say I regularly (or ever) create Powershell classes on the fly. Can see how it would be useful over a collection of NoteProperties though, if the use case justifies the extra work to devise a class dynamically.